# Не удаётся создать сервер сокета на php

Tags: php, сокет

Вот правильно? Но не могу подключиться клиентом

```
<?php
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
$socketClients = array($socket);
if ($socket != false) {

$result = socket_bind($socket, '0.0.0.0', 12342);
if ($result !== false) {

     $result = socket_listen($socket, SOMAXCONN);         

     socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);

     socket_set_nonblock($socket);

    if ($result !== false) {
        while (true and time() - $time < 20) {

            $newSock = socket_accept($socket);


            if (is_resource($newSock)) {
                echo '<br>connect' . $newSock;
                $socketClients[] = $newSock;
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo '<br>нельзя прослушать';
    }
} else {
    echo '<br>нету бинда';
}
} else {
    echo '<br>not socket ';
}

socket_close($socket);
```

Comment: Что вы делаете? Приведите код демонстрирующий проблему чтобы другие могли повторить.

Comment: В чем именно проблема? Что означает, не можете подключить?

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Вообщем разобрался с причиной не подключения. **Хостер не позволяет открывать порты!!**